# Want to Convert Amount to words in Indonesian Language

Tags: vb.net

Please help me fix my code that is intended to translate a `Double` value into its Indonesian language description.

My code is not giving the correct translations e.g. 12.2 does not translate correctly.

```vb
Imports System

Public Function ConvertDecimalToWords(decimalNumber As Double) As String
    Dim result As String = ""

    ' Define arrays for words in Indonesian
    Dim units() As String = {"", "satu", "dua", "tiga", "empat", "lima", "enam", "tujuh", "delapan", "sembilan"}
    Dim tens() As String = {"", "sepuluh", "dua puluh", "tiga puluh", "empat puluh", "lima puluh", "enam puluh", "tujuh puluh", "delapan puluh", "sembilan puluh"}

    ' Split the decimal number into its integer and fractional parts
    Dim integerPart As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(decimalNumber))
    Dim fractionalPart As Integer = CInt(Math.Round((decimalNumber - integerPart) * 100))

    ' Convert the integer part to words
    If integerPart > 0 Then
        result = ConvertToWords(integerPart) & " koma "
    End If

    ' Convert the fractional part to words
    If fractionalPart > 0 Then
        result &= ConvertToWords(fractionalPart)
    Else
        result &= "nol"
    End If

    ' Function to convert a number to words
    Function ConvertToWords(number As Integer) As String
        If number < 10 Then
            Return units(number)
        ElseIf number < 20 Then
            Return tens(number - 10)
        Else
            Dim digit As Integer = number \ 10
            Dim remainder As Integer = number Mod 10
            Return tens(digit) & " " & units(remainder)
        End If
    End Function

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Ther's a lot to address here. Firstly, please look at the preview of your question and don't submit if the formatting is a mess. If you don't know how to format properly, use the Help Center to learn. It's just a text editor like any other, so I would hope you know how to use one. Secondly, don't add a bunch of irrelevant tags to your question to trick people into reading it. Use tags that apply only directly to the issue. There's nothing here relating to UiPath, Python or even C#.

Comment: Finally, SO is not a place where you say "I want to do X, give me code". We are here to help with specific issues, not to just write your code for you. You have provided your existing code but you have not given any indication of what's wrong with it. You need to explain exactly how and where the code behaves differently to how you expect. If you don't know that then you need to work it out first, before posting. Debug the code and step through it line by line, examining the state at each step. Where the state does not match your expectations, that's the issue.

Comment: Please do not close this question, it is a really interesting problem. The Asker is having trouble converting the fractional part of the number to words

Comment: @SSS being an interesting problem is necessary but not sufficient to being a good Stack Overflow question.  It needs to be clear what the problem is so that the question and answer will be useful to more than just the person asking the question.

Comment: @Craig, I feel the Asker has provided enough info... he is trying to turn numerals into Bahasa equivalents.

Comment: @Sohil Bagwan it would be good if you can give some example values that are not translating correctly, and the correct translation for them

Comment: @SSS I think the latest edit helps, but it would also be helpful to say what the translation is now and what it should be.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things you need to change.

1. Make the arrays private in the module
2. Move the ConvertToWords() function outside the other function
3. Use String manipulation to extract the fractional part of the number

(not sure #3 is required, I can't really speak Bahasa)

```
  ' Define arrays for words in Indonesian
  Private units() As String = {"", "satu", "dua", "tiga", "empat", "lima", "enam", "tujuh", "delapan", "sembilan"}
  Private tens() As String = {"", "sepuluh", "dua puluh", "tiga puluh", "empat puluh", "lima puluh", "enam puluh", "tujuh puluh", "delapan puluh", "sembilan puluh"}

  Public Function ConvertDecimalToWords(decimalNumber As Double) As String
    Dim result As String = ""

    ' Split the decimal number into its integer and fractional parts
    Dim integerPart As Integer = Math.Truncate(decimalNumber)
    Dim fractionalPart As Integer = 0
    Dim decimalString = decimalNumber.ToString
    Dim dotPos = decimalString.IndexOf(".")
    If dotPos > -1 Then
      fractionalPart = Val(decimalString.Substring(dotPos + 1))
    End If

    ' Convert the integer part to words
    If integerPart > 0 Then
      result = ConvertToWords(integerPart) & " koma "
    End If

    ' Convert the fractional part to words
    If fractionalPart > 0 Then
      result &= ConvertToWords(fractionalPart)
    Else
      result &= "nol"
    End If
    Return result
  End Function

  ' Function to convert a number to words
  Function ConvertToWords(number As Integer) As String
    If number < 10 Then
      Return units(number)
    ElseIf number < 20 Then
      Return tens(number - 10)
    Else
      Dim digit As Integer = number \ 10
      Dim remainder As Integer = number Mod 10
      Return tens(digit) & " " & units(remainder)
    End If
  End Function
```